# Zahl als Wort: "einskommasechs" oder "eins Komma sechs"?

Tags: capitalization

Wenn man Zahlen als Worte schreibt, was passiert mit dem Komma?

"Hundertsiebzehntausendvierhundertdreiundachzig" ist ja ein Wort. "Einskommasechs" auch?

Der Duden [meint zwar](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Schreibung-von-Zahlen) "siebenhundertzweiundvierzig Komma fünfundachtzig", aber das will mir nicht einleuchten, denn es sieht dämlich aus. Geht es auch anders?

---

*Zur Erklärung.*

Ich schreibe einen Roman. Die Konvention sieht vor, wörtliche Rede in der Literatur so zu schreiben, wie sie gesprochen wird. Nun spricht man aber keine Ziffern – man sagt nicht: "5" (das Zahlzeichen könnte ja auch "five" oder "cinq" gesprochen werden) –, sondern Zahl*wörter*: man sagt "fünf".

In einem Dialog heißt es deshalb nicht:

> Thomas sagte: "Die Mohrrüben kosten €1,20 / kg."

sondern:

> Thomas sagte: "Die Mohrrüben kosten eins zwanzig je Kilo."

Und das ist nicht egal, sondern äußerst wichtig, denn €1,20 / kg kann man ja auf ganz unterschiedliche Weise sprechen, und so unterscheiden sich die Figuren in einem Roman denn auch darin, wie sie das sagen:

> Roberta aber sagte: "Nein, die Mohrrüben kosten einen Euro und 20 Cent."

was Roberta etwas pedantischer erscheinen lässt als Thomas.

Gleichwohl schreibt man die wörtliche Rede in einem Roman aber üblicherweise korrekt nach den Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung. Man schreibt nicht "fÜnv", sondern "fünf". Und deshalb ist es eben auch nicht beliebig, wie ich das mit dem Komma handhabe, denn die Rechtschreibung dient der Verständlichkeit und man weicht von ihr besser nur überlegt und selten ab.

Comment: Es sieht lange nicht so dämlich aus wie "siebenhundertzweiundvierzigkommafünfundachtzig". So etwas würde man nur im krassesten stream-of-consciousness-Stil schreiben, also wenn **alle** Leerzeichen geopfert werden.

Comment: Für "Komma fünfundachtzig" bekommt man Ärger. Das heißt "Komma achtfünf". Aber ob man das jetzt so schreibt weiß ich leider nicht.

Comment: @Kai    Wenn du im Supermarkt an der Kasse stehst, sagst du aber auch nicht "sieben Euro Komma fünf null" sondern "sieben Euro fünfzig".

Comment: @KilianFoth Das Duden-Beispiel "hundertsiebzehntausendvierhundertdreiundachzig" (von dort gecopypasted) ist aber auch nicht Stream of Consciousness, sondern entspricht den Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung. Dagegen sieht mein "einskommasechs", obwohl es offenbar falsch ist, doch lesbar und verständlich aus. Und gar nicht wie Stream of Consciousness. Finde ich.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann genausowenig wie du "sieben Euro Komma fünfundachtzig" sagst. Du läßt (hoffentlich) das "Komma" weg. Und schon ändert sich was. Denn was du da eigentlich wegläßt ist nicht das "Komma", sondern "Cent" am Ende.

Answer (score 3):

Hier gehts es weniger um Rechtschreibung als um eine schriftsetzerisch-ästhetische Entscheidung.

Der Fall, den du schilderst, ist ja in der Praxis höchst selten: Wann wird man schon Zahlen (vor allem dieser Länge) in Worten ausschreiben, und dann noch Kommazahlen? In aller Regel tut man das nicht. Wenn du es trotzdem tun möchtest, hast du einen spezifischen Grund dafür. Vielleicht schreibst du ein Theaterstück oder du arbeitest am wörtlichen Transkript einer gesprochenen Äußerung, und deine Transkriptionsregeln sagen dir, dass du alles in Worten notieren sollst.

In solchen Sonderfällen würde sich die Auswahl der Schreibung der Zahlen idealerweise an den jeweiligen Zweck des schriftlichen Elaborats anpassen. Geht es zum Beispiel bei dem Transkript um irgendwelche quantitativen Analysen zum Vorkommen von Einzelwörtern, dann bestimmt die Methodik dieser Analyse, was du als Einzelwort notieren solltest. Das hat mit Rechtschreibung dann gar nichts mehr zu tun.

Auf jeden Fall liegen verschiedene sinnvolle Möglichkeiten der Schreibung auf der Hand.

> siebenhundertzweiundvierzig Komma fünfundachtzig
>
> siebenhundert zweiundvierzig Komma fünfundachtzig
>
> siebenhundertzweiundvierzigkommafünfundachtzig
>
> sieben hundert zwei und vierzig Komma fünf und achtzig
>
> siebenhundert-zweiundvierzig-Komma-fünfundachtzig

Ich persönlich würde dann vermutlich die zweite Variante vorziehen, und zwar weil die Trennung (Leerzeichen) weitgehend den Aussprachegewohnheiten folgt, und somit wird das Lesen und Verstehen einfacher. Ebenso (oder gar noch besser?) gefällt mir die fünfte Lösung, denn hier wird einerseits das Lesen erleichtert (durch Trennung wie in der gesprochenen Sprache), andererseits wird die Zahl durch die Bindestriche doch wieder als jene Einheit dargestellt, die sie ja auch als 742,85 im Schriftbild wäre.

---

**Nachdem die Frage präzisiert wurde...**

Mit den neuen Erläuterungen zur Ausgangsfrage - dass es sich nämlich um einen Roman handelt, in dem die Zahlen ausgeschrieben werden sollen:

Hier würde ich einen Kompromiss suchen zwischen Dudentreue, Schriftbild, Lesbarkeit und Schlankheit (Unauffälligkeit, Unaufdringlichkeit, Natürlichkeit).

Wir setzen nun natürlich voraus, dass es für den Roman aus irgend einem Grunde wichtig ist, dass nicht einfach

> Das Eis kostet zwei dreißig.

gesagt wird, sondern dass Dinge mit langwierigen Zahlen gesagt werden wie

> Hey, Commodore, da ist ein Fehler in der Rechnung. Die Wgrlprmf-Galaxie ist gar nicht zweiundachtzig Komma vier fünf Megaparsec entfernt, sondern zweiundachtig Komma vier acht!

das heißt, dass die Zahlen in dieser Exaktheit eine Rolle spielen (zum Beispiel weil sich daran dann später die Auflösung der großen Frage des Romans knüpft). Denn wenn sie es nicht täten, läge es ja nahe, simplere Zahlen zu nehmen, die sich leichter in Worten ausdrücken lassen.

Und natürlich ist es immer einer Überlegung wert, die Zahlen eben doch als Zahlen zu schreiben also

> Hey, Commodore, da ist ein Fehler in der Rechnung. Die Wgrlprmf-Galaxie ist gar nicht 82,45 Megaparsec entfernt, sondern 82,48!

Das ist auf jeden Fall einfacher und angenehmer zu lesen. Und es folgt der guten Praxis auch in anderen Texten, z.B. Zeitungsartikeln, Fachbüchern, Zeitschriftenaufsätzen, dort, wo Zahlen eine größere Rolle spielen und häufig vorkommen, sie auch als Zahlen zu schreiben. Zum Beispiel wird man in einem Zeitungsartikel zwar in der Regel dem Duden folgen (der ja auch nur wieder der guten Schriftsetzerpraxis folgt) und Zahlen bis zwölf in der Regel buchstabieren, ab 13 dann in Ziffern setzen, doch wenn es im Artikel z.B. um die Zahlen aus der Haushaltsplanung der Gemeinde geht, wird man unter Umständen schon der Einheitlichkeit wegen dann doch alle Zahlen als Zahlen schreiben, also

> Im Sozialbereich werden 1,3 Millionen Euro veranschlagt; für Verkehr und Grünflächen sind 3 Millionen vorgesehen.

Dies wäre eigentlich die normale, gute Praxis auch in einem Roman.

Du müsstest schon einen stichhaltigen (künstlerisch-konzeptionellen) Grund haben, in deinem Roman durchweg auf buchstabierten Zahlen zu bestehen.

---

**Ergänzende Anmerkungen**

Man sollte aber auf keinen Fall in einem Roman und anderen Texten, die nicht rein finanzieller Art sind, Dinge wie *€ 1,20* schreiben, also mit einem Währungszeichen vorne dran. Dies ist eine Buchhalter- und Kaufmannsmarotte, teils auch ein Amerikanismus. Ein allgemeinsprachlicher Text in gutem Stil folgt auch hier den Sprechgewohnheiten. Man schreibt billigerweise *1,20 Euro, 5 Millionen Euro, 70 Eurocent*.

Comment: Wenn "Komma" als eigenes Wort abgetrennt wird, greifen für die beiden verbleibenden Zahlen aber die Regeln der deutschen Rechtschreibung, wo nach § 36 (1.6) Zahlen zusammengeschrieben werden. Dann bleibt nur die erste Variante.

Comment: @IQV  Ich finde, du siehst das zu legalistisch. Die Regeln deutscher Rechtschreibung sind kein Gesetz, an das sich die Bürger des Landes zu halten haben (andernfalls ihnen Straf- oder Zivilrecht drohten), und wir sind hier ja auch, denke ich doch, in einem Bereich, der so speziell ist, dass Rechtschreibregeln nicht mehr recht fruchten. Wenn es einen guten Grund gibt, von ihnen abzuweichen - und das dürfte hier der Fall sein - dann macht man das einfach.

Comment: Kluge Überlegungen, Christian. Die Begründung, warum ich Zahlen ausschreibe, habe ich in meiner Frage ergänzt: In literarischen Texten werden Zahlen in der wörtlichen Rede gewöhnlich als Worte geschrieben. Weil man nicht Zahlzeichen, sondern Worte spricht.

Comment: Ich schlage vor, im Titel der Frage "als Wort" durch "in wörtlicher Rede" zu ersetzen. Dass der geschrieben Text nicht wiedergibt, was bei lautschriftlicher Umsetzung herauskäme, halte ich für selbstverständlich. Für peniblen Umgang mit Sprache würde ich trotzdem ein zündenderes Beispiel suchen.

Answer (score -1):

Das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Komma#wb-1) sieht es wie der Duden, aber natürlich kannst **Du** schreiben wie es **Dir** gefällt.

Comment: Und **wie** sehen es die beiden? Das sollte in Deiner Antwort unbedingt auch stehen (falls die Links sterben, die Frage verändert wird, oder die Antworten irgendwannmal in ein Dupe-Merge eingehen).

Comment: Klar, ich kann auch ohrfeigen, wen ich will. Die Frage ist halt, ob es mich meinem Ziel näher bringt, von meinen Lesern zum einen verstanden und zum anderen gerne gelesen zu werden.

Comment: @Takkat, ich denke, dass es genügt, dass es in der Frage steht. Eigentlich finde ich ohnehin, dass sie als 'primarily opinion-based' geschlossen werden sollte.

Answer (score -1):

Der Duden deckt deinen Anwendungsfall voll ab:

> Bei der Darstellung von Beträgen mit Dezimalstellen wird die Zahl der
>   Cents durch ein „Komma" abgetrennt; die Nennung des Kommas ist dabei
>   freigestellt:
>
> 742,85 = siebenhundertzweiundvierzig (Komma) fünfundachtzig.
>
> Werden die Währungseinheiten konkret angegeben, wird das Komma nicht
>   genannt:
>
> 742 Euro, 85 Cent = siebenhundertzweiundvierzig Euro fünfundachtzig
>   Cent.

Da du schon geschrieben hast dass du gerne zwei Charaktere mit unterschiedlicher Diktion darstellen willst, wirst du wohl die beiden oben dargelegten ("eins [Komma] zwei" und "ein Euro zwei Cent") nehmen müssen - die Optionalität des Kommas gibt dir sogar noch Raum für einen dritten Zahlwort-charakterisierten Protagonisten. 
Falls noch mehr Abwechslung nötig ist, gibt es ja noch die "zwo" und "fünef" -Varietäten der Zahlwörter.

Das Komma in das Zahlwort einzugliedern ist nicht vorgesehen, und wird wie jede andere Variation auf die übliche Vorehensweise dann eben als besonders und bemerkenswert wahrgenommen - wenn das gewünscht ist: ideal.